# PHP Script works on one site but not other, same server

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

I currently have a cPanel server, I have a domain site1.com we created the new website on the server using cPanel. The problem is that our script that was used to create the the site runs on the test site "site2.com" on the same cPanel server but does not run on the new site site1.com

If have narrowed the issue down to this line 18 in EditPage.php:

```
header("Location: Login.php?Page=$PageToEdit");
```

The only difference I can se on the server is that "site1.com" is running "PHP7.4 PHP-FPM" in the cPanel and "site2.com" "PHP7.4" there is no way to turn "PHP-FPM" on or off in the cPanel so what is deciding to turn it on for some sites and not for the others? And why is it even needed make no sense. I'm a newbie so please be specific thanks!

```
SERVER:
cPanel Version  98.0 (build 6) - 
Apache Version  2.4.48 - 
PHP Version 7.4.22 - 
MySQL Version   10.3.31-MariaDB - Architecture  x86_64 - 
Operating System    linux - 
Kernel Version  3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64
```

PHP script that fails:

```
// (A) START SESSION
session_start();
 
// (B) LOGOUT REQUEST
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) { unset($_SESSION['user']); }
 
// (C) REDIRECT TO LOGIN PAGE IF NOT LOGGED IN
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  header("Location: Login.php?Page=$PageToEdit");
  die();
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is not working - the redirect? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: No error is thrown just get white page and this source:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Online Editor</title> 

and that's it.

Comment: _"no error is thrown just get white page"_ - and exactly that is the reason, why you need to go and check the log files! And make sure proper error reporting level & logging are configured for the sites to begin with.

Comment: if I null out:

  //header("Location: Login.php?Page=$PageToEdit");
  //die();
  
  it works "but" user bypasses login. and I have even remove all coding in "Login.php" to echo "Hello"; to consolidate the possibility of other errors somewhere.

Comment: All error reporting is on also used this with no luck.

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: You should rather make those settings via cpanel, than directly in code. And, again, my question: Have you checked the actual error log on the server by now? It is quite unlikely that you'd get a 500 error, but then no traces of what actually went wrong in the logs.

Comment: AGAIN -> No error is thrown just get white page and this source: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"> <title>Online Editor</title> and that's it. If you look at the fix you will see that it was a header issue that didn't throw a error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of session is not destroying. We can unset session with these functions.

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = [];
```

Now it will work. Your code should like this

```
// (A) START SESSION
session_start();

 // (B) LOGOUT REQUEST
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) { unset($_SESSION['user']); 
 session_destroy(); $_SESSION = []; }

 // (C) REDIRECT TO LOGIN PAGE IF NOT LOGGED IN
 if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
     header("Location: Login.php?Page=".$PageToEdit);
     die();
 }
```

Comment: OK now at least we get a error:

Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /domain.com/code/system/library/EditPage.php on line 13

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /domain.com/code/system/library/EditPage.php:1) in /home/domain/public_html/domain.com/code/system/library/EditPage.php on line 21

Comment: now you are using session_start() function two times in a page or file.

Comment: Here is what I did
`code`
// (A) START SESSION
//session_start();

 // (B) LOGOUT REQUEST
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) { unset($_SESSION['user']); 
 session_destroy(); $_SESSION = []; }

 // (C) REDIRECT TO LOGIN PAGE IF NOT LOGGED IN
 if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
     header("Location: Login.php?Page=".$PageToEdit);
     die();
 }

Comment: GET:
 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home//public_html/domain.com/code/system/library/EditPage.php:1) in /home/smldesign/public_html/domain.com/code/system/library/EditPage.php on line 21

Comment: FIXED! removed header from Login.php THANKS Mudassar!